# Network connects slowly or not at all

Tags: wireless

Okay, so my network card id is f6d6050. I use `ndiswrapper` and have it all correctly installed. Funnily though, I have to run `sudo modprobe -v ndiswrapper` every time I log on in order for it even to bother searching for a network. The problem here though, as you can probably guess from the title, is that most days it takes 5-10 minutes to successfully connect to the network. Most times it asks several times to confirm my network key, and it will occasionally even refuse to connect until I restart my computer.

Any ideas? Is there any code that may be helpful in finding out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo su 
echo ndiswrapper >> /etc/modules 
exit
```

That should make your connection start automatically and hopefully will speed up the connection time too.

Comment: Well that actually did solve the automatic problem, which is great. I never figured out how to find rc.local and add a script there, so that's great, but the connection still feels a little bit sluggish. It wasn't as slow as usual though, which I guess is an improvement so thank you.